# SQL Server inside CDATA block of XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, cdata

The meaning of $> inside the CDATA block.I am trying to understand the part inside the CDATA block of an XML code file,the parts where $> is used.What is the use of it?

```
<sqlTask name='LOGIN_USER'>
            <![CDATA[
                SELECT owner_id $>REGISTRAR_PK, SYSDATE $>TIMESTAMP, ops\$rs3.report_seq.nextval $>REPORT_ID
                  FROM ops\$rs3.smdi_owners
                 WHERE user_name = UPPER($LOGIN_USER)
            ]]>
            <error text='Registrar: $LOGIN_USER - Unknown user.'/>
        </sqlTask>
```

Comment: It looks like a scripting language where the $> indicate a parameter.

Comment: It's not an XMLism, nor something specific to CDATA. It'll have meaning to something that *consumes* this XML.